# Do reflexive separable Banach spaces have Schauder bases?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

I know there exists an example in the literature due to Per Enflo of a separable Banach space without a Schauder basis. I am wondering if there is a reflexive counterexample?

If so I would greatly appreciate a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example of a separable reflexive Banach space with no Schauder basis appears in:

*Szarek, Stanislaw J.*, [**A Banach space without a basis which has the bounded approximation property**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392555), Acta Math. 159, 81-98 (1987). [ZBL0637.46013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0637.46013).

(I haven't read the paper beyond the statement of the theorem.)

Comment: Enflo's example was reflexive. [Here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-130/issue-none/A-counterexample-to-the-approximation-problem-in-Banach-spaces/10.1007/BF02392270.full) is a link to it.